# Helly-Bray theorem for weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{\mu_n\}_{n \geq 1}, \mu$ be probability measures on $(\Bbb R, B(\Bbb R))$. Then I need to prove that $\mu_n => \mu$ implies $\int fd\mu_n -> \int fd\mu$ where $f$ any bounded and continuous function

The proof given in the text starts by choosing $K$ large enough such that $\mu((-K, K]) > 1 - \epsilon$ and then choosing $a \lt -K$ and $b \gt K$ such that $\mu(\{a\}) = \mu(\{a\}) =0, a, b \in D$ where $D$ is a dense set where vague convergence holds.

I don't understand the necessity of the mass zero points here ? I don't understand where they have been used in the proof.

Comment: We want to use $F_{\mu_n}(t)\to F_{\mu}(t)$, but it may be not true if $F_{\mu}$ is not continuous at $t$.

Comment: yes, but converges in distribution implies vague convergence which implies $\mu_n((a,b]) -> \mu_((a,b])$ for all $a,b$ in a Dense set. I don't understand why do we need to choose zero mass point here. I think I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Please give your definition of weak convergence.